# Amazon S3 public by default to user "Everyone"

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I've followed the S3 documentation and haven't had been able to allow with public access by default.

Here is the code that I applied to the bucket policies:

```
{
"Version": "2008-10-17",
"Id": "Policy1424204422650",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "Stmt1424204398740",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": {
            "AWS": "*"
        },
        "Action": "s3:GetObject",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::images/*"
    }
]
}
```

I've tried to change the principle to "Everyone", however AWS returns the following error:

```
Invalid principal in policy - "AWS" : "Everyone"
```

How would I modify the JSON to allow access to everyone by default?

Comment: Have you used the correct [ARN](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/aws-arns-and-namespaces.html#arn-syntax-s3) for your bucket for the Resource part?

Comment: Yes my bucket name is images

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [S3 example bucket policies](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/example-bucket-policies.html#example-bucket-policies-use-case-2) have the correct policy- I google it every few months.

```
{
  "Version":"2012-10-17",
  "Statement":[{
    "Sid":"AddPerm",
    "Effect":"Allow",
    "Principal": "*",
    "Action":["s3:GetObject"],
    "Resource":["arn:aws:s3:::examplebucket/*"]
  }]
}
```

There's only one thing you should change, and that's `examplebucket`.

Note the principal is `"*"`, and it isn't a hash/dict.

Comment: unless you created that bucket name 8 years ago, there's *no way* your bucket name is "images". They must be globally unique, I'm sure that was taken soon after launch.

Comment: its actually 'vinimages', I think I have it formatted correctly though

Comment: Can you edit the question to show how you are trying to access items?

Comment: I've added a few screenshots of how I am accessing the items through the console.

Comment: You can successfully apply the policy- I want to see where/how you are trying to access objects that it is failing.

Comment: I am accessing the S3 through cyberduck and adding the permissions through there currently. I've added a screenshot.

Comment: You still haven't shown the access and failure from 'public'. I'm giving up- not enough information is provided, despite my requests.